# Problem with plotting 3D elliptic paraboloid

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'm looking to plot 3D functions using R. For example, take the elliptic paraboloid given by `f(x,y) = (−2−1)^2 + (3+−2)^2`. Here's what I've tried:

```r
require(lattice)
x <- seq(-10, 10, by=0.5)
y <- seq(-10, 10, by=0.5)
g <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
g$z <- (x-2*y-1)^2 + (3*x-y-2)^2
wireframe(z ~ x * y, g, drape = TRUE,
          aspect = c(1,1), colorkey = TRUE)`
```

And here's the output

[image: 3d surface]

However, here's the "true" graph of f:

[image: another 3d surface]

I've tried changing the definitions of `x` and `y`, to no avail. I've also tried the `curve3d()` function from the `emdbook` package. It looks even worse.

Answer (score 2):

You multiplied by the wrong `x` and `y`. You need to use the ones inside `g`:

```
g$z <- with(g, (x-2*y-1)^2 + (3*x-y-2)^2)
wireframe(z ~ x * y, g, drape = TRUE,
          aspect = c(1,1), colorkey = TRUE)
```

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: It seems there's still something wrong with it... but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong?  Or what was wrong with the `emdbook::curve3d` output?

Comment: adding ` scales=list(arrows=FALSE)` will give you tick marks etc.